# CAN BUS : CAN_BUSY returned but other node recieved the previosus message

Tags: can, digital-communications

I have two can nodes in a CAN bus.
node1 send messages periodically , node2 received only the first message (I can check with a CAN tool)

for the first message, CAN_OK is returned for send routine. but for the second message, CAN_BUSY is returned.

what are the possibe reason of getting CAN_BUSY when the first meessage is ACK and properly received by other node

This is the CAN controller of [S32K148EVB: S32K148 Evaluation Board](https://www.nxp.com/design/development-boards/automotive-development-platforms/s32k-mcu-platforms/s32k148-evaluation-board-for-general-purpose:S32K148EVB)

Comment: There is no universal CAN_BUSY status. What device (make/model/software) are you using that returns this status?

Comment: This is CAN controller-specific and pretty much impossible to answer without knowing the controller and looking at the source code of the driver.

Comment: I updated the question with the hardware information

Comment: The problem is likely in the source code of the driver. Some flag which wasn't cleared correctly perhaps. S32 is apparently using FlexCAN, which is a modern controller with mailbox functionality. How you send and receive messages depends on if you are using FIFO or mailboxes. From what I remember you have to assign a bunch of mailboxes to serve as generic tx ones, unless you use dedicated mailboxes for all messages.